# How come 18650 Li-ion cells aren't meant to be sold loose?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo

I've heard that 18650 Li-ion cells aren't meant to be sold loose. They're meant to be built into packs and the "good" manufacturers won't actually sell them for any other purpose. FWIW, there's the Panasonic NCR18650 - which I believe are sold loose.

So, my question is: why aren't 18650 cells (perhaps LiPo cells in general, for that matter) meant to be sold loose?

Comment: You can buy personal quantities loose from a variety of sources. But Samsung, LG, Panasonic will have to approve of your end use application if you want to establish a supply chain. If your device blows up with their cells in it, it reflects poorly on them. There are many subtleties to designing a safe battery pack, especially for transportation applications with vibration, mechanical stress, and high discharge rates.

Answer (score 5):

"Not meant" is not completely meaningful as there is not a consistent international regulation to that effect.

However, an 18650 cell is potentially rather dangerous and use without an accompanying  protection circuit module is extremely unwise. The norm is to either have one protection module per cell or to use a multi-cell module which connects to all cells in a pack directly. While it is notionally possible to connect multiple cells in series and to "protect" the combination the notion is not a good one. LiIon cells tend to best live long and prosper when the individual cells can be individually managed.

Vcell too high, cell dies, maybe with flame or just degrades.
Vcell somewhat low, life reduces.
Vcell very low - will not recover and attempts at charging may cause flame.
I discharge too too high and flame will happen.
I charge too high and damage will happen BUT most protection cctc do not prevent this.

Selling unprotected cells to unqualifed buyers is a bad idea.
Selling protected cells to unqualified buyers may be a bad idea -  destruction of cells and equipment is still "easy enough".
An 18650 cell is rated at perhaps 10C or about 25A and probably capable of 50-100A in short bursts (possibly VERY short & just before flame) depending on model and maker.
A 4S 18650 stack is an awesomely capable beast - maybe a kW+ burst output capable.

Comment: Indeed, until recently you couldn't buy loose Li-ion cells  (18650, prismatic cells) for the reasons which Russel have described.  In the last few years, something have changed.  It's now possible to buy loose 18650 on consumer market (incl. Amazon).  There are now portable devices that accept only 18650.  I wonder, what has changed?  Do we now have a safer Li chemistry?  Do these 18650 for consumer use have built-in protection circuits?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I think the huge e-cigarette market has forced this situation

Answer (score 0):

I think your premise is incorrect. From what I can see, Sparkfun (online) and Jaycar (brick and mortar in Australia) sell these cells. They're not very common so I guess the local supermarket or gas station won't be selling them but they're obviously readily available.

Comment: The O.P.'s premise is not all that invalid.  Li-ion cells are considered [hazardous materials](http://www.rosebatteries.com/lithium_regulations.asp).  What enables Sparkfun, Amazon to sell these cells loose, I'm curious to find out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The link you provided just stated the package should be labelled. No issue with that, is there? There isn't any restriction on the sale, except for package quantities.

Answer (score 0):

A high quality 18650 Li-Ion cell will have internal protection devices which limits discharge current in the event of an external short circuit. I once did an investigation and attempted to replicate an explosion/fire by short-circuiting high quality fully charged Li-Ion 18650 cells. Although the temperature of the cell increased I could not create a catastrophic failure. (This was done in a controlled laboratory environment.)

There will be low-quality cells as well and the outcome may be different. Sad state when a "manufacturer" is willing to place unrealistic (and unverified) mAh figures on a cell just to get some sales.